# SQL insert to fill an associative table with conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-server-2008-r2, associative-table

I have two tables and an associative table between them (let's call them `Tab1`, `Tab2` and `ATab`).

`Tab1` and `Tab2` have those very same fields (for example purpose) :

- `Id`.
- `Name`.

In my `ATab`, I want to insert record to associates `Tab1` and `Tab2` with their Ids.

In order to do so, I would like to write my query in a sql script that say something like :

I can manage to do something like :

```
INSERT INTO ATab(Tab1Id, Tab2Id) 
SELECT Tab1.Id, ????? 
FROM Tab1 WHERE Tab1.Name='Foo';
```

But I'm selecting only the `Foo` record of my first table...

How would I manage to perform a "double" where clause ? Is it possible ?

Comment: Oh dear... :) Seems that I was looking way to far >.<

Comment: Ill make it an answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by using `AND`

```
INSERT INTO ATab(Tab1Id, Tab2Id) 
(SELECT Tab1.Id, Tab2.Id
FROM Tab1, Tab2 WHERE Tab1.Name = 'Foo' AND Tab2.Name = 'Bar')
```

Comment: no problem :), just added `, Tab2` before the where clause as well